# delay issue when replaying a wav sound in onClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a wav sound that plays when button is pressed and when i attempt to play this again while the sound is still playing there is a short delay and does not start properly as intended! i am trying to have the sound play clean and fast on every press at anytime, here is my java code thank you

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();




        final ImageView bellImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bellImage);

        bellImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loopMP();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ding2);
                mp.start();

            }
        });

    }

    public void playMusic() {

        if (mp != null) {
            mp.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {

            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void loopMP(){
        if (mp != null){ mp.stop(); mp.release(); mp = null; }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of release() and create() the mediaplayer object every time user clicks the button, try to create() only once. Then inside of onClick(), try seekTo(0) to rewind from the beginning of the media file, then call start() to play again.

Comment: im not sure i understand, in the onClick i have a loop so that the sound can be played again at any moment! could you show me an example of what you mean? thank you